# PHP link on submit button

Tags: php

Boas,
Preciso de uma funcao em PHP, ja que em HTML não consigo, para listar os ficheiros com uma determinada extensao,(html) e mosta-los numa combo box, ou dropbox. Depois necessito que ao seleccionar um ficheiro e premir o botao, abra o ficheiro corespondente. neste momento, funciona tudo com excepcao de que ao premir o botao aparece o link que tenho de premir para abrir o ficheiro. como faer para abrir logo assim que se prime o botao ?

Obrigado!

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<?php
$files = glob('*.html');
echo "<select name='datas'>";
foreach ($files as $file) {
echo "<option>".$file."</option>"; }
echo "</select>";
?>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Seleccione a Data" />
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
$selected_val = $_POST['datas'];
echo "<a href=$selected_val>$selected_val</a>";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Jovem aqui é o PT.StackOverflow, por favor edite sua pergunta escrevendo em português.

Comment: Traduzido. Obrigado pela chamada de atenção,

Answer (score 0):

Somente com PHP você poderia utilizar a função `header('Location:' . $endereco)`.

Ficaria assim em PHP:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        $selected_val = $_POST['datas'];
        header('Location: ' . $selected_val);
    }
?>
```

Outra alternativa é utilizar um simples JavaScript.

**Uma pequena mudança no corpo do HTML**

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <?php
            $files = glob('*.html');
            echo "<select id='idcombobox' name='datas'>";
            foreach ($files as $file) {
                echo "<option>".$file."</option>"; 
            }
            echo "</select>";
        ?>

        <input type="button" name="submit" onclick="abrirPagina()" value="Seleccione a Data" />
    </form>
</body>
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script language="javascript">
    function abrirPagina(){
        console.log("teste");
        var combobox = document.getElementById("idcombobox");
        var itemSelecionado = combobox.options[combobox.selectedIndex].text;
        window.location.href = itemSelecionado;
    }
</script>
```